# How to generate inverted normal random numbers in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, random-number-generator

I am trying to generate 5.000 random variables using these excel functions: `normsinv(rand())`. This is the code I wrote:

```
Dim r As Integer
r = 1
For r = 1 To 5001

.Cells(r + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd())

r = r + 1

Next
```

However, when I execute nothing happens (but it does not accuse any error as well)...
Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Should it be `Rand()` not `Rnd()`?

Comment: [VBA code instead of NORMSINV(RAND())](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/vba-code-instead-of-normsinvrand/219e3d66-231a-413f-a0ff-f0bd60dfec26) might also help you ...

Comment: [Generating random numbers with Excel](http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/966/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:A5001")
    r.Formula = "=normsinv(rand())"
    r.Copy
    r.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```